# intelliSense error in c#

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0, intellisense

I am trying to create a setup project and adding the existing project to it.But i can see 3 solutions of my new setup project and if i try to run the code gives me the intelliSense error.Is it trying to rename my application ? and also i am trying to add the existing 2 projects along with setup.exe and one of my application is coded in .net 3.5 and other in 4.0. Is this creating any problem. I read many examples in online and din't find the relevant code.

```
    IntelliSense: cannot open source file "C:/project/workspace/code/MyApplication/Application1/Debug/libid:AC0714F2-3D04-11D1-AE7D-00A0C90F26F4.tlh"   c:\project\workspace\code\myaplicationl\application1\stdafx.h   48  2   MyAppliation
```

how can i resolve this???

I am using c# win forms .net 2010

Comment: Did you try a Build->Clean? There might be something leftover from a previous build throwing it.

Comment: @lc.-i did all that but it throws the same error all the time if i try to build it.

Comment: check http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcprerelease/thread/efdf4ae8-437d-4a7f-8cf5-b895257da2bd

Answer (score 1):

Try compiling the StdAfx.cpp file in every project that has one. .tlh files are automatically-generated files that are created by the #import directive (that's C++). But of course you need to compile any files that have #import directives in order for the .tlh files to be generated.

Comment: @user1610015-how should i compile this? this is included in the project alone..?

Comment: In Solution Explorer, look for StdAfx.cpp, right-click it and select **Compile**. Do it for the StdAfx.cpp file in every project if there is more than one.

Comment: it is not giving me any option to compile, it seems to be disabled(ctrl+F7).

Comment: @user1610015- its allowing me to compile but should i have to compile all .cpp files?

Comment: No, only the StdAfx.cpp file in each project. Technically you need to compile any file that contains an #import directive (or that includes any header that contains an #import directive), but that's usually just StdAfx.cpp

Comment: @user1610015- it shows some error line in #import //The following #import imports the IDTExtensibility2 interface based on it's LIBID
 #import "libid:AC0714F2-3D04-11D1-AE7D-00A0C90F26F4" version("1.0") lcid("0")  raw_interfaces_only named_guids --  in the code of stdafx.h

Comment: @user1610015- #import //The following #import imports the IDTExtensibility2 interface based on it's LIBID #import "libid:AC0714F2-3D04-11D1-AE7D-00A0C90F26F4" version("1.0") lcid("0") raw_interfaces_only named_guids --- this is the error

Comment: I think that's the line with the error, but what error message do you get from the compiler? I would guess it's most likely about the type library not being registered.

Comment: @user1610015-error i have posted above this IntelliSense: cannot open source file "C:/project/workspace/code/MyApplication/Application1/Debug/libid:AC0714F2-3D04-11D1-AE7D-00A0C90F26F4.tlh"   c:\project\workspace\code\myaplicationl\application1\stdafx.h   48  2   MyAppliation" and same i get in error list.

Comment: That's the IntelliSense error, but you haven't told me the error from the compiler when you try to compile StdAfx.cpp (which appears in the **Output** window/panel). BTW it would be faster to talk about this on IM, do you have msn or something?

Comment: @user1610015- it compiles well with no errors but when building entire project it hits. No i am not allowed to install anything of that sort to my system in company.

Comment: OK, all I'm saying is that the following (in bold): **//The following #import imports the IDTExtensibility2 interface based on it's LIBID #import "libid:AC0714F2-3D04-11D1-AE7D-00A0C90F26F4" version("1.0") lcid("0") raw_interfaces_only named_guids** is not the error from the compiler, it looks more like code. The other error: **"C:/project/workspace/code/MyApplication/Application1/Debug/libid:AC0714F2-3D04-‌​11D1-AE7D-00A0C90F26F4.tlh" c:\project\workspace\code\myaplicationl\application1\stdafx.h 48 2 MyAppliation** is an IntelliSense error, not a compiler error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23467/discussion-between-roopini-n-and-user1610015)